# Как реализовать несколько форм в одном окне

Tags: c++-cli

Я создаю приложение на C++ через WinForms, есть несколько форм. И нужно чтобы по нажатию на кнопку в главное форме, открывались не новые окна, а появлялись они на главной форме. Я в С++ еще плохо разобрался, так что хотелось бы с какими-нибудь конкретными примерами.

Comment: C++ и C++/CLI - два **разных** языка. На C++/CLI полноценные приложения не пишут. Точка. Он используется только в качестве "клея" между управляемым (.NET) и неуправляемым кодом. / Если хотите освоить настоящий C++, то забудьте о WinForms (и вообще откажитесь на время от Visual Studio).